# Do Elements in subfolders count into parent list elements count?

Tags: 2013, list, folder

Are the elements in a subfolder also counting into the elements of the specific parent list?

Or is the folder a separat "list" which is independent from the parent list?

I am asking regarding the maximum level of elements in a list and if I can do a workaround with moving the files into a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders are list items however they do *not* impact the list view threshold in the same manner because when you create a new folder it creates a new internal index. You will still be constrained to 5000 parent folders but you can then also add 5k items to each of those folders (including child folders to repeat the process). This allows you to safely go beyond the threshold.

Do note that the threshold will still affect some actions (any views that do not include folders and anything that uses CAML behind the scenes).

To answer your questions specifically: Yes folders and their contents are still counted as part of the list threshold but only for actions that impact the entire list. For document views it will work fine.

Yes you can store more items in a list without impacting the threshold by using folders.

Comment: to which of my two question is the answer `yes`? they are both not the same

Comment: Yeah sorry, edited for clarity. Let me know if that does not make sense.

Comment: perfect! thank you very much. This helps me a lot!